# /etc/passwd file is corrupt and i cannot change it i also cannot login as root

Tags: passwd

I have attempted to change the file /etc/passwd in ubuntu server 12.04 and I tried to change the root username.  I only changed one part of the root username this is what i have:

```
main:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
                [ Read 53 lines (Warning: No write permission) ]
```

The top line where it says main needs to say root.  I cannot change this file because no other user has sudo access.  This is a server hosted by another company so I cannot access recovery mode or the live boot disc.
Thanks,
Bryce Pruett

Comment: Does `pkexec nano /etc/passwd` work?

Comment: I hope `pkexec` trick works. ...but **why**? Personal advice: download VirtualBox, install an Ubuntu server in it, and do this kind of dangerous things in it first. The problem in logging is as `main` is probably because you changed only `/etc/passwd` and not the other files (`/etc/shadow`, `/etc/passwd-`, group files, etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you lose access to an install like this where you have no physical access to, you're completely at the mercy of your host, their feature-set and how willing to bend-over backwards they are for you.

- If you have virtual console access (or your host has it - ask them), they might be able to log in as root, either directly or through recovery mode. Some hosts (Linode for one) have this as a feature but some will require a real person at their end.
- Or you could beg them to do a local fix where they mount your filesystem for you and do the fix. I have no idea whether or not they'd even be willing to do this, let alone how much it would cost.
- If that doesn't pan out you could ask them for a disk dump. You send them a disk, an image to it and send it back and you fix the file... And send it back and they restore from it. This is not a standard arrangement that hosts have with their customers. Expect to pay for postage in 4 directions and at least ~$100 for their time.

It's still a long-shot with some hosts.
Basically this process is going to teach you how good your host really is. Good hunting.